# JQuery Sly Plugin Left Force

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Have a next [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9dJfQ/11/) with JQuery Plugin. situation next:
If you click on an item, it moves to the left. How to make that item is shifted itself without clicking?

```
var sly = new Sly($('.frame.left'),{
horizontal: 1,
itemNav: 'basic',
activateOn: 'click',
mouseDragging: 1,
startAt: 0,
speed: 300,
activeClass: 'active',
})
sly.on('active', function(eventName, activatedItemIndex){
sly.toStart(activatedItemIndex)
})
sly.init();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To auto trigger a click, you can use something like:

```
$(".slide .item").eq(3).trigger("click");
```

Which will trigger the 4th item.

**[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9dJfQ/14/)**

Comment: Here some [code](http://jsfiddle.net/9dJfQ/15/). But it need to upgrade. Can you?